# QVector: проблема с итератором

Tags: qt, c++

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с итераторами при создании вектора с элементами типа своего класса.

```
int main(){

    QVector<myClass> vector;
    myClass x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        x.x=i;
        x.y=i;
        vector.push_back(x);
    }
    QVector<myClass>::iterator iter=vector.begin();

    for (;iter!=vector.end();++iter)
    {
        qDebug()<<*iter.x;
    }
}
```

Сам класс:

```
class myClass
{

public:

    myClass();
    int x,y;
};
```

Пробовал ставить тип элемента вектора `int`, все работает. В документации нашел примеры только со стандартными классами.

Comment: В данном случае class избыточен. Используйте struct :-)

Comment: здравствуйте,я написал для примера)суть проблемы в другом,у меня не выходит работать с вектором с помощью итератора, элементы которого являются объектами класса.
надеюсь,я правильно изложил мысль.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток! Сам маялся с аналогичной проблемой. Для того чтобы использовать итераторы, для своего класса, а также использовать его в в различных типизируемых структурах типа List<> требуется определить для своего класса некоторые из следующих конструкций: конструктор по умолчанию, шокирующим конструктор, оператор сравнения =, а также возможно функцию получения бэла от вашего класса. Точно какие необходимы - сказать сложно для каждого из типизируемых классов этот набор свой, но они нужны, если у вас вопросов что это, я могу покопаться и выслать вам пример своего класса, работающего с такими типами.
Вот мой пример, который я, в свое время, взял из документации по Qt, частично дополнил и использовал, как основу в последующих классах:

**Message.h**

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H
#define MESSAGE_H

#include <QHash>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>

class Message
{
public:
    Message();
    Message(const Message &other);
    ~Message();

    Message(const QString &body, const QStringList &headers);

    QString body() const;
    QStringList headers() const;

    friend bool operator==(const Message& left, const Message& right);
    friend uint qHash(const Message& message);
private:
    QString m_body;
    QStringList m_headers;
};

#endif // MESSAGE_H
```

**Message.cpp**

```
#include "message.h"

Message::Message() {
}

Message::Message(const Message &other) {
    m_body = other.body();
    m_headers = other.headers();
}

Message::~Message() {

}

Message::Message(const QString &body, const QStringList &headers) {
    m_body = body;
    m_headers = headers;
}

QString Message::body() const {
    return m_body;
}

QStringList Message::headers() const {
    return m_headers;
}

bool operator==(const Message& left, const Message& right) {
    return !left.body().compare(right.body());
}

uint qHash(const Message& message) {
    return ::qHash(message.body());
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то возможно, что часть из этих конструкций не нужно определять, т.к. компилятор сделает их по умолчанию.

Ссылка на документацию:

Comment: [Ссылка на документацию:][1]

The values stored in the various containers can be of any assignable data type. To qualify, a type must provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator. This covers most data types you are likely to want to store in a container, including basic types such as int and double, pointer types, and Qt data types such as QString, QDate, and QTime, but it doesn't cover QObject or any QObject subclass (QWidget, QDialog, QTimer, etc.).

 [1]:http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/containers.html

Comment: If you attempt to instantiate a QList<QWidget>, the compiler will complain that QWidget's copy constructor and assignment operators are disabled. If you want to store these kinds of objects in a container, store them as pointers, for example as QList<QWidget *>.

Comment: MaSTeR_Alexandr, если вам не сложно, было бы очень классно)

Answer (score 0):

Ты разыменываешь int, а не итератор.
Правильно так: iter->x или (*iter).x

Comment: Да и итератор не знает ничего об x ( нельзя написать iter.x)